# PauseMenu - FPS Camera still moves when in PauseMenu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Whenever I pause everything stops, that's how I want it to be, but the only thing that does not stop is the camera. I move my cursor the camera still follows. I want it to freeze. I am using the FPS Controller Asset in the asset store

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
     static bool IsPaused = false;

     public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
         {
             if (GameIsPaused)
             {
                 Resume();
             } else
             {
                 Pause();
             }
         }
     }

     public void Resume()
     {
         pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
         Time.timeScale = 1f;
         AudioListener.pause = false;
         GameIsPaused = false;
     }

     void Pause()
     {
         pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
         Time.timeScale = 0f;
         AudioListener.pause = true;
         GameIsPaused = true;
     }

     public void LoadMenu()
     {
         Time.timeScale = 1f;
         SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
     }

     public void QuitGame()
     {
         Debug.Log("Exiting Game");
         Application.Quit();
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the reference to the Character Controller Script and then disable it:

```
mycharfpscon.enabled = false;
```

And then enabble it back:

```
mycharfpscon.enabled = true;
```